# Run Destination Not Valid For Running Scheme Xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, ide

Just downloaded Xcode and I am trying to run a simple C++ file to make sure everything works and whenever I try to run the .cpp file I am given this: "The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'Scheme_Name'.

Comment: just set the SDK to MacOS X 10.6.

Comment: @pkc456 How do I set the SDK?

Comment: 1) Click on the project icon in the left hand panel. 2)select Build Settings » all. 3) You'll see the option to change the SDK.
img546.imageshack.us/img546/9808/picture3fh.png

Comment: I can only set the SDK to "macOS", I'm not able to set a version of macOS. I'm using Xcode 10.1 (10B61). The error persists with this setting.

Answer (score 44):

happened the same to me with a project I downloaded. In my case, the solution was to change the "Base SDK" to the latest OS X in the Build Settings.

To do so, click on the project name in the navigator on the left, then on `Build Settings` and in the main window you should look for `Base SDK`.

If `Base SDK` does not show, ensure that "All" is selected in the filter at the top of the page.

[image: Base SDK set to 10.10 in this example]

Comment: hm, i'm having these exact symptoms with a Library project of my own, and after xcode 7 the library won't archive w/ this same message. I also had osx10.9 in the settings, but bumping it to latests isn't helping.

Comment: oh, I see my problem. My library has multiple targets and I was setting the Base SDK on the wrong target. this works. thank you.

Comment: For possible other Xcode newbies like myself, I'll elaborate on @orionelenzil 's comment above - the "targets" are shown in a drop-down on the topmost toolbar in the above screen shot, over near the left end. (Blurred out in the above screen shot.)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the same issue when I duplicated and renamed a project. I solved by setting the Build Target in the Scheme Edit view.
[image]