# Xcode project doesn't compile, "the run destination My Mac is not valid for [...]"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, open-source

I've just downloaded the [`configd` tarball from Apple's open source repository](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/configd/configd-801.10.2.tar.gz) since I've had some problems with `configd` and I wanted to explore the possibility of patching the source, but (even without any changes to the source, just after opening the .xcodeproj file) the project won't compile.

I've downloaded the latest version of Xcode from the App Store but attempting to build the project with any of the schemes just leads to the error

> "The run destination 'My Mac' is not valid for running the scheme *[name]*."

I know C programming but I'm new to OS X development and the Xcode IDE, so how do I need to configure the project so it won't refuse to build? Are there any further SDKs I need to download? Do I need to change the run destination to something more appropriate? (The intended destination is the same PC Xcode is running on.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33094641/4151918

Comment: @PetahChristian thanks a lot, the initial error is gone (replacing "macosx.internal" SDK by "macosx" SDK seemed to work) but now the build fails because the header "os/log.h" can't be found. Do you know which SDK this belongs to or where to obtain it? (OS X 10.11.1)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33708029/730172 it might be helpful.